# How to debug in a large software system?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Using debugger isn't an efficient way to debug in a large software system with my components and dependencies. Most people use logger to log critical or informational messages into log file. Is that true? Any recommendation on how to debug large software?

I am using IntelliJ or Eclipse.

Comment: What exactly is inefficient about using debuggers in large software projects? Have you done it yourself, or has someone else just told you that?

Comment: This is why people utilize unit tests

Comment: I worked on a project which had gigs of Java files. And was some 15 years old. Hundreds of developers worked on the code. But still used Eclipse Debugger to fix most bugs. What makes you think that with large codebase it is not possible to use debugger?

Answer (score 1):

Debbugging directly is always the most efficient (and fastest) way to found bugs in your software... problem is: you cannot always use it. Imagine a production environment, almost surely you don't have the grants nor the possibility to stop your software for a debug session. But you can always log on file system or database tables the critical information about your software execution and possible errors. My advice is, put your software in an environment where you can directly (or remotely) debug it AND at the same time add meaningful logs too speed up the bug solving.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the software to debug, but generally, the debugger is a very powerful tool. You just need to know where the bug hides most probably. You don't want to set a breakpoint in the very first line of your `main` method, which is why it might help to ask yourself the following questions:

- Is the bug most likely a GUI bug (strange looking views) or is it potentially a backend bug?
- What module/dependency/part of the program is responsible for the task that is faulty?
- If you have logs available, do they contain any stacktraces?
- It can also help to copy a log message and search for it in the codebase to see where the log message is posted.

However, once you know roughly where to look for the faulty code, it comes down to using the debugger: Set your breakpoint where you think the bug might be, fire the debugger up and get cracking. Again, you don't want to debug your entire program, but once you found the sore spot, the debugger is a very powerful tool.

Comment: In my unit test, it starts another JVM and the code enters into an external package and the break point in my code is not reachable. How to deal with this situation?

Comment: Great! Then you know that the problem sits in the external package or in  the call to that package. So go ahead and check if you are calling the package correctly and if yes, debug that package if you can.

Comment: But why do you call an external package in a unit test in the first place?